# Exception setting Http response header 'Glimpse-RequestID'

Tags: glimpse

I'm attempting to get Glimpse running on a server. The way that IIS is set up here is that a site is mapped to what appears to be an external domain, but in fact is a local IIS project. The windows "hosts" file maps the "site.foo.com" domain to the 127.0.0.1, and "site.foo.com" is then added as a binding to the site in IIS. I mention this because it's almost certainly important, as I don't know if it means it appears as a local or remote request, even from the browser on the local machine

To get the Glimpse icon to even appear from requests on the local machine, I updated the web.config ignore some of the runtime policies (as the log was complaining about those):

```
  <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd">
    <!-- If you are having issues with Glimpse, please include this. It will help us figure out whats going on. -->
      <logging level="Trace" />
  <runtimePolicies>
    <ignoredTypes>
        <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
    <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy, Glimpse.Core"/>
    <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy, Glimpse.Core"/>
     <add type="Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy, Glimpse.Core"/>
    </ignoredTypes>
  </runtimePolicies>
  </glimpse>
```

The icon now appears, but nothing happens when I click it, and the following appears in the log

```
2013-04-15 13:10:00.7978 | ERROR | Exception setting Http response header 'Glimpse-RequestID' with value '6991f828-b716-40b1-9362-56dfd64b6440'. | System.Web.HttpException--Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.--   at System.Web.HttpResponse.AppendHeader(String name, String value)
   at Glimpse.AspNet.AspNetFrameworkProvider.SetHttpResponseHeader(String name, String value)
```

any ideas what I need to look at next?

thanks

Comment: It is not recommended to ignore the `StatusCodePolicy` or `ContentTypePolicy`. Doing so will cause Glimpse to activate for all requests, including static files such as images. Remove those two lines from your `.config` file and report back if you still have the `AppendHeader` issue.

Comment: Thanks @TobyEvans. Are you by chance flushing the response manually? It seems like you may have found a bug in Glimpse. Would you mind posting the steps to reproduce this on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)?